How to pass null body through playwright request?
I have a POST request with null as the body. I am not sure how to pass this null through a Playwright POST request.
I tried with data: null, data: 'null', data: Null, data: '%00', data: {}. All these fails the test at the line where I catch the response body as await resp.body().
If I pass null in Postman for the same request, I get a successful JSON response. If no null in the Postman request, I get 'content type error' as response.
var api_context = await request.newContext();
var resp = api_context.post('url',{
headers:{
content-type:'application/json',
Authorization: auth_token},
data:null});
var resp_json = await resp.json();

Have you tried not supplying the data property at all?

Postman always adds some headers. Inspect them, and try to replicate relevant ones  in your code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you share some code of the requestBody?

Are you using APIRequestContext (request.post)? Please edit your question to make it clear. The HTTP protocol doesn't have a null concept. Are you asking about sending an empty request body?

Please show your full request.

I tried not sending data at all, it didn't work as well. Request body in the network tab is mentioned as null. Post man too gives response if I enter null in the body.

I missed 'await' on reuest. Issue is not due to null payload. Mentioning payload as data:null worked.

Post the solution in a separate answer
